# Unable to set a lambda's role from CDK

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have the following code:

```py
EventbridgeToLambda(
    self,
    "Some",
    lambda_function_props=lambda_.FunctionProps(
        code=lambda_.InlineCode(lambda_code),
        handler="index.lambda_handler",
        runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
        # Set timeout to something other than 3 seconds
        timeout=Duration.seconds(45),
        layers=[lambdaLayer],
        environment={
            "S3_BUCKET": "dev_environment_bucket",
        },
        role=iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self, id="x", role_arn="arn:aws:iam::numbers:path/rolename", mutable=True
        ),
        vpc=ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "VPC", vpc_id="vpc-0hex"),
        allow_public_subnet=True,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnets=[ec2.Subnet.from_subnet_id(self, "Subnet", "subnet-0hex")]
        ),
        security_groups=[ec2.SecurityGroup.from_lookup_by_id(self, "SG", "sg-0hex")],
    ),
    event_rule_props=events.RuleProps(
        schedule=events.Schedule.cron(
            minute="*", hour="0-3,11-23", day="*", month="*", year="*"
        )
    ),
)
```

If I manually install/create this lambda, there is a specific role I need to set in the Configuration->Basic Settings->Edit panel. If I forget to set this role, then when I go to set up the configuration in Configuration->VPC, the correct vpc/subnet/security-groups are not available to choose from the list.

The above CDK code will work to set arbitrary vpc/subnet/security-groups, I've tested it and that part seems to work. However, I am unable to figure out why I'm not able to set the role. When I attempt to synth/deploy, I receieve the following warnings/errors:

```
WARN AWS_SOLUTIONS_CONSTRUCTS_WARNING:  An override has been provided for the property: role[physicalName].
WARN AWS_SOLUTIONS_CONSTRUCTS_WARNING:  An override has been provided for the property: role[grantPrincipal].
WARN AWS_SOLUTIONS_CONSTRUCTS_WARNING:  An override has been provided for the property: role[roleName].
WARN AWS_SOLUTIONS_CONSTRUCTS_WARNING:  An override has been provided for the property: role[roleArn].
WARN AWS_SOLUTIONS_CONSTRUCTS_WARNING:  An override has been provided for the property: role[policyFragment][principalJson][AWS][0].
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cfnOptions')
      at Object.addCfnSuppressRules (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-VO2cY2/node_modules/@aws-solutions-constructs/core/lib/utils.js:138:18)
      at deployLambdaFunction (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-VO2cY2/node_modules/@aws-solutions-constructs/core/lib/lambda-helper.js:135:17)
      at Object.buildLambdaFunction (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-VO2cY2/node_modules/@aws-solutions-constructs/core/lib/lambda-helper.js:33:20)
      at new EventbridgeToLambda (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-VO2cY2/node_modules/@aws-solutions-constructs/aws-eventbridge-lambda/lib/index.js:23:40)
      at Kernel._create (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/tmpucsljbww/lib/program.js:9964:29)
      at Kernel.create (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/tmpucsljbww/lib/program.js:9693:29)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/tmpucsljbww/lib/program.js:11544:36)
      at KernelHost.run (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/tmpucsljbww/lib/program.js:11504:22)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/private/var/folders/_0/8_jcp7n556xdgnb70mfxh95m0000gn/T/tmpucsljbww/lib/program.js:11505:46)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    SomeStack(app, "DataIngestion", env=Environment(account='numbers', region='us-east-1'))
  File "/Users/john/Projects/z-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 112, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/Projects/z-data-ingestion-v2/cdk_stacks/lambdasSomeStack.py", line 43, in __init__
    EventbridgeToLambda(self, 'Some',
  File "/Users/john/Projects/quext-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 112, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john/Projects/z-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_solutions_constructs/aws_eventbridge_lambda/__init__.py", line 204, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "/Users/john/Projects/z-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 334, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
  File "/Users/john/Projects/quext-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 363, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
  File "/Users/john/Projects/z-data-ingestion-v2/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 340, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cfnOptions')
```

I can use this role when configuring Lambdas manually. It is pre-existing, I'm not trying to create a new one. The syntax seems correct. I suspect that there is some missing configuration that I need to set if I need a role other than default, but it's unclear what that'd be. I saw something in the documents about how sometimes it's necessary to remove the path portion of the ARN, and I've tried it both with and without that. Without the path portion, the stack trace is identical, except that the last line says `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')`. I assume this is because it's expecting the path to be present.

iam.Role.from_role_name() behaves similarly.

I'm just trying to match with CDK what I can do by hand. What am I missing or failing to understand?

Comment: So if you do not pass the `role` prop, it synths fine? What does "path" mean in the ARN? It should be "role".

Comment: @gshpychka Yes. And with a sandbox account that has a different setup (no need to change the role to see a list of vpcs), it's sufficient. With the proper account where I need the role set to see a list of vpcs, this fails because they don't have access to that vpc.

Comment: That's not right - it would not fail to synth due to insufficient role permissions, as the role permissions are not known at synth time. It could only fail during deployment, not synth. Can you address the the "path" question as well, want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @gshpychka If you say so. I've posted the (big) warning/error/stacktrace from it. I'm not entirely sure what it means. It is as if it was expecting another configuration option that is missing "cannot read properties of undefined". I do not understand any of this well enough to make sensible guesses though. I was hoping someone would laugh, point at it and say "that's stupid, you forgot X, and you don't do Y that way".  If I leave out "role=" entirely, then it merely complains that it can't find the vpc, which of course it can't because I can't do that either manually, without the role 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you probably is using [aws-eventbridge-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-eventbridge-lambda.html) from [AWS Solutions Constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/welcome.html), which provides a default lambda function role for you and does not allow you to override.

See [Pattern Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-eventbridge-lambda.html#pattern-properties) for more details.

If you are still getting `the role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda`, it's generally because the imported role does not have trust policy for lambda service. You should have a trust policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you should consider to create that role with CDK. Consider the following example:

```js
export class DemoStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    const myRole = new iam.Role(this, 'DummyRole', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'),
      ],
    });

    const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'Func', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
      code: lambda.Code.fromInline('def handler(event, context): return "Hello CDK!"'),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      role: myRole,
    });
    new CfnOutput(this, 'Role', { value: func.role?.roleArn! });
    new CfnOutput(this, 'FuncName', { value: func.functionName });
  }
}
```

Test with `aws lambda invoke`:

```
% aws lambda invoke --function-name demo-stack-Func217E03A4-l5p0MYvPZFHX outfile && cat outfile
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
"Hello CDK!"
```

Comment: Having read your answer, I realized you might be right. I removed the Solution Constructs code, and I think I have something like a normal setup now. I create the lambda itself, a rule, and attach the rule to it (vice versa). I still receive similar errors if I try to set the role though.

Comment: I take that back... it's letting me set the role now, and only complains that "the role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda". That sort of feels like success. Almost there.

Comment: @JohnO Just updated my answer above :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update @PahudHsieh. I still get the "cannot be assumed". But the role has a bunch of other permissions the lambda needs, I can't just create a new one for this. I will talk to devops and have them make certain the trust policy allows that.

Comment: It actually turns out that I can create a role for this, that could work. I just then have to create my own vpc for it, and for that I have to create my own security group and subnets. But I don't know how to configure them because I don't have permissions to see the config of the existing one so I can copy it. Devops should get back to me in a few weeks. Pray for me.